# How do I get the name of the currently signed-in Visual Studio user in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

Does anyone know how to get the name of the user who's currently signed into Visual Studio from C#?

Basically I want my VS extension to be able to greet the user by name (ie whoever's signed in to the current VS session).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38264088/get-identity-of-logged-in-visual-studio-user-from-extension?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT I haven't started coding that feature yet, so I'll either post an update if the current solution is sufficient, or I'll ask for more help if it doesn't. Of course if I find an even better solution I'll be happy to report it back here. Thanks for the follow-up.

Comment: @YannDuran Hi friend, any update for this issue? Maybe you can easily check if the code works in a console app since it actually can work in many situation. Just a reminder:)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there's no API in VS SDK can support this behavior. So you may have to code to read the related value about current account from Registry using [Register.CurrentUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry.currentuser?view=netframework-4.8).

Check the [answer from Hadi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31378023/10910450) and thanks to him, I think it's what you're after. And it works well for VS2015 and VS2017 after my test.

Comment: Can EnvDte be used to find this info?

Comment: @dfhwze Haven't found correct or related api, do you mean [Process.UserName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte80.process2.username?view=visualstudiosdk-2017#EnvDTE80_Process2_UserName) or something like this. I can't get it to work to get account-related user name:(

Comment: EnvDte is an interop library for the VS IDE: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte?view=visualstudiosdk-2017. Perhaps it has methods to get the signed in user.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT thanks for that.I tried searching StackOverflow a few times, and Google several times, but did see that answer. I guess I just didn't have the right combination of search terms. Someone in the extendvs Gitter room suggested the registry, but I had hoped that by 2019 that there'd be a "better" way of getting such a simple thing. I'll give Hadi's code a try. Thanks again!